# Sveltekit how to tell browser not cache any asset like css and image and js

Tags: sveltekit

in Sveltekit,  how to tell browser not cache any asset like css and image and js?

I want browser to fetch image js and css everytime, every request. not using it from cache.

my sveltekit app is hosting on vercel

I try some of the setheaders in sveltekit, but they don't seem to work at all

```js
// +page.server.ts
export const load: PageServerLoad = async (event: any) => {
    const token = event.locals.token
    try {
        const res = await getDataServer(api.getShippingAddress, token)
        event.setHeaders({
            'cache-control': 'max-age=5',
        })
        return res
    } catch (error) {
        return { data: [] }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *should* not need to do anything like that because all assets are hashed if used via imports. If they change, the hash changes and thus the URL, causing a cache miss.

Comment: not really, some multiple refresh won't reflect the latest change in css. I don't know why it's like that

Comment: Then you probably did not use the use the assets correctly (e.g. by putting them in `static`). Show your actual code.